# Identity framework tries to insert new object when I want to reference an existing object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am making a web app using blazer and identity framework. I would like the object `BoardYear` to have a one-to-one relation with `Member` as chairman which is an IdentityUser class and selected by a dropdown.

When I try to insert a new `BoardYear` with an exciting `Member` as chairman I get the following SQL exception.

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (de20c079-ed99-4bf9-9474-d8eb1a05b5b6).

It seems like Entity Framework wants to add the referred `Member` to the database, which is not possible because it already exists.

The member class:

```
public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Guid? ChairmanBoardYearId { get; set; }
    public BoardYear ChairmanBoardYear { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Boardyear class:

```
public class BoardYear
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BoardYearId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Member Chairman { get; set; }
}
```

The relation is configured in the dbcontext like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Member>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<BoardYear>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Chairman)
            .WithOne(b => b.ChairmanBoardYear)
            .HasForeignKey<Member>(m => m.ChairmanBoardYearId);

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<BoardYear> BoardYears { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Commission> Commissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CommissionFine> CommissionFines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MemberFine> MemberFines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MeetingFile> MeetingFiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MemberSanction> MemberSanctions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CommissionSanction> CommissionSanctions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<YearGroup> YearGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CommissionList> CommissionLists { get; set; }
}
```

When the dropdown is edited the chairman is assigned like this in the razor page (I can see it gets the correct member):

```
async void OnBoardUserChange()
{
    Member selectedMember = await MemberService.FindMember(selectedChairmanId);
    curBoardYear.Chairman = selectedMember;
}
```

And then put in the database in the following service:

```
public class BoardYearService
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;
        private readonly DidaDbContext _db;

        public BoardYearService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public async Task<int> Create(BoardYear boardYear)
        {
            using (var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                CommissionList boardYearCommissionList = new CommissionList();
                boardYear.CommissionList = boardYearCommissionList;
                ctx.BoardYears.Add(boardYear);
                return await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, so which line of your code makes such error and what is your `_contextFactory` Please share more details. From the error message, it means you add data with duplicated primary key. What is the data of `boardYear`?

Comment: Hello, @Rena I've added the dbcontext and service class. The error occurs on the `ctx.SaveChangesAsync();` line. `boardYear` has all properties filled. The chairman property is an identity member that already exists in the database. I'd like the board to reference this member instead of adding it to the database. The memberservice uses the same `ApplicationDbContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have retrieved the user from whatever context instance MemberService.FindMember uses, but are referencing it in a BoardYear added to a new context instance.

The second context instance, where the BoardYear is added is not tracking the Member, so assumes it is an addition.

Either perform the whole action using data retrieved and persisted back through the same context instance, or just use an Id field on the BoardYear instead of a navigation property.

Comment: I using only one dbcontext, I do use a IDbContextFactory in the services to create a dbcontext. Can this be part of the problem? I did this because I use Blazor Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: There's no problem using a factory to create the context instance.  But, you must use the same instance for the retrieval and the update.  In your code, you are creating a new instance before adding BoardYear.

Comment: You where right I used an old dbcontext I thought I did not use.